# Exclude some lines of php code from sonarqube analysis

Tags: php, sonarqube, code-analysis

Is there a way to exclude some lines of code from sonarqube analysis without excluding the whole source code file? Maybe with an annotation or something like this?

I'll give you an concrete example, where i need to exclude a certain code smell for an unused function parameter:

I implemented a validation method like this:

```
public function validateTruth(string $attribute, $value) : bool
{
    $acceptable = [
        '0',
        0,
        'false',
        false,
        '1',
        1,
        'true',
        true,
        'no',
        'yes',
    ];

    return in_array($value, $acceptable, true);
}
```

in order to extended the \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory with the extend method:

```
$validationFactory->extend(
    'truth',
    Validator::class . @validateTruth',
    'The :attribute field must be some kind of truth value.'
);
```

My implementation doesn't uses all the required parameters, but i cannot just leave out the first parameter. The extend wouldn't work with a callback method without the $attribute parameter. So the extend method clearly requires a callback with a certain set of parameters, but it doesn't provide an interface or something like this, so the missing parameter would be excluded automatically from sonarqube.

Is there a way to exclude only this code smell, without excluding the whole function or file from sonarqube analysis? I would prefer a solution within the source code, because we use different instances of sonarqube in our development lifecycle, so flagging such code smells in the webfrontend would be harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the issue via the web-ui, or, if you prefer to do it in the code, mark it with a `NOSONAR` comment.

See [the official FAQ](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-HowtoremoveFalse-Positiveissues?) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The proposed solution with the //NOSONAR  comment seems to work for the sonar runner. But this comment doesn't seem to work in the IDE (at least for PHP) although there was a closed issue for SonarLint for IntelliJ at https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-20

Comment: @GordonGünther Which IDE are you using? In my IntelliJ I just verified, that `NOSONAR` works fine. Still: IntelliJ will keep raising its own issues on those lines. Try this: `long i = 0l;` (1 IntelliJ issue + 1 SonarQube issue) and later that: `long i = 0l;//NOSONAR` (1 IntelliJ issue).

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm and after i restarted the IDE it worked.