# SonarQube PHP //@codingStandardsIgnoreStart / End equivalent code block ignore

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm analyzing a PHP project with Sonarqube 6.4 using the PHP plugin and while we develop, we use the PSR2 //@codingStandardsIgnoreStart //@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd in order to ignore broken rules in a block of code. That lavels are not working with sonarqube analysis and
NOSONAR only works for a line of code as far as I know. But I want an ignore way for a block of code.

I saw Sonarqube had something similar in the past using //CHECKSTYLE:OFF / ON. 
Is there a way to do that with the Sonarqube 6.4 version for PHP projects?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not the same question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183653/exclude-some-lines-of-php-code-from-sonarqube-analysis
I want to know if there is a method to ignore a block of code as it was on the past. But I think there is no one right now... (I didn't found it). Not only //NOSONAR that works for one line (as far as I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to exclude *areas* of code from the analysis.

You can, however

- Mark the issues as *False-Positive* or *Won't Fix* in the SonarQube UI
- Mark lines with a `NOSONAR` comment
- Exclude whole files from the analysis

See [the official FAQ](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-HowtoremoveFalse-Positiveissues?) for more details.

Comment: Oh... I'll try to add an improvement for a future Sonarqube versions. Thank you!